# tar / pack `a-r` "unreadable" files

Tags: permissions, tar, chmod, file-metadata

If there are files unreadable even to the owner (`chmod a-r`), `tar` and other tools will throw errors when creating an archive. However, these files *could* be updated with `chmod u+r` before archiving, and `chmod u-r` after unpacking -- so they are not actually unreadable.

How can such files be archived with their exact permissions? I guess one generate a `permissions-restore` script (with `stat`), run `chmod u+r`, run `tar`, and keep both the archive and the permissions script. Actually, mtime would have to be saved as well (since chmod destroys it). Anything simpler?

Comment: you can always tar with sudo... that way you'll preserve permissions AND be able to read the file